# How to put the caption of a subfigure in table style (or array style)

Tags: tables, subfloats, arrays, subcaption

I have the following code to put some figures alongside.

```
\begin{figure*}[!htb]{
 \subfigure[test]{\label{fig:test}\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{test.pdf}}
 \end{figure*}
```

This code works correctly. I want to have a table in the subcaption of the subfigure, but putting array or tabular does not work. I've tried the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}[!htb]{
 \subfigure[
  $\begin{array}{cc}
  a & b \\
  c & d
  \end{array}$
  ]
  {\label{fig:test}\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{test.pdf}}
 }
 \end{figure*}
```

Do you have any suggestions? I have multiple subfigures, so using subfigure is necessary.

Comment: From you use of the `\subfigure` command, I guess you use the `subfigure` package. Please be aware that this package is considered obsolete. Use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: @leandriis Many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: There appears to be an extra `{` right after both `\begin{figure*}[!htb]`. You should receive an error message informing you about that, when trying to compile your document.

Comment: @leandriis Oh yes, that was a mistake coming from copying part of the code, edited now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the desired output, switch from the deprecated `subfigure` package to either `subcaption` (as shown in the following example) or `subfig` and remove the extra `{`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!htb]
 \subfloat[
  $\begin{array}{cc}
  a & b \\
  c & d
  \end{array}$
  ]
  {\label{fig:test}\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}
 \end{figure*}
 
 \end{document}
```